# How to scrape all product review from lazada in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i currently working on web scraping of data from the lazada site using selenium in python: 
https://www.lazada.sg/products/loreal-paris-uv-perfect-even-complexion-sunscreen-spf50pa-30ml-i214861100-s325723972.html?spm=a2o42.seller.list.1.75895319pt8HKU&mp=1

However, i am only able to extract out the first page of the product review. Does anyone know how to extract review from page2?

Here are the codes (but there is error that Element is not clickable at point from the codes below):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


url = 'https://www.lazada.sg/products/loreal-paris-uv-perfect-even-complexion-sunscreen-spf50pa-30ml-i214861100-s325723972.html?spm=a2o42.seller.list.1.75895319pt8HKU&mp=1'
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(0.1)

review_csv=[]
product_csv = []
rating_csv =[]
date_review_csv = []

titles = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pdp-mod-product-badge-title').text
print(titles)
product_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='item']")

urls = []

#Page 1 of product review
for product in product_reviews :

    review = product.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='content']").text
    if(review != "" or review.strip()):
        print(review)
        review_csv.append(review)
    else:
        print(review)
        review_csv.append("No comments/review is an image")

    #Product Purchase
    #Check if the product purchase exists

    product_purchase = product.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='skuInfo']").text
    print(product_purchase)
    product_csv.append(product_purchase)


    #Star rating
    star_ratings = product.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='star']")
    stars = "https://laz-img-cdn.alicdn.com/tfs/TB19ZvEgfDH8KJjy1XcXXcpdXXa-64-64.png"

    star_rate = 0
    for rating in star_ratings:
        #print(rating.get_attribute('src'))
        if(rating.get_attribute('src') == stars):
            star_rate = star_rate + 1
    rating_csv.append(star_rate)
    print(star_rate)

    # Date of Review
    date = product.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='title right']").text
    date_review_csv.append(date)
    print(date)

#Page 2 of product review onwards
page2_product_reviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="module_product_review"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/button[2]').click()
for product in page2_product_reviews :

    review = product.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='content']").text
    if(review != "" or review.strip()):
        print(review)
        review_csv.append(review)
    else:
        print(review)
        review_csv.append("No comments/review is an image")

    #Product Purchase
    #Check if the product purchase exists
    product_purchase = product.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='skuInfo']").text
    print(product_purchase)
    product_csv.append(product_purchase)


    #Star rating
    star_ratings = product.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='star']")
    stars = "https://laz-img-cdn.alicdn.com/tfs/TB19ZvEgfDH8KJjy1XcXXcpdXXa-64-64.png"

    star_rate = 0
    for rating in star_ratings:
        #print(rating.get_attribute('src'))
        if(rating.get_attribute('src') == stars):
            star_rate = star_rate + 1
    rating_csv.append(star_rate)
    print(star_rate)

    # Date of Review
    date = product.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='title right']").text
    date_review_csv.append(date)
    print(date)


driver.close()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do pagination use `infinite` while loop and #Check for **button** `next-pagination-item` have `**disable**` attribute then jump from loop else click on the next button.

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.lazada.sg/products/loreal-paris-uv-perfect-even-complexion-sunscreen-spf50pa-30ml-i214861100-s325723972.html?spm=a2o42.seller.list.1.758953196tH2Mn&mp=1")
review_csv=[]
product_csv = []
rating_csv =[]
date_review_csv = []
titles = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pdp-mod-product-badge-title').text
print(titles)
while True:
      #Get the review details here
      WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.item")))
      product_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='item']")

      # Get product review
      for product in product_reviews:

          review = product.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='content']").text
          if (review != "" or review.strip()):
              print(review)
              review_csv.append(review)
          else:
              print(review)
              review_csv.append("No comments/review is an image")

          # Product Purchase
          # Check if the product purchase exists

          product_purchase = product.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='skuInfo']").text
          print(product_purchase)
          product_csv.append(product_purchase)

          # Star rating
          star_ratings = product.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='star']")
          stars = "https://laz-img-cdn.alicdn.com/tfs/TB19ZvEgfDH8KJjy1XcXXcpdXXa-64-64.png"

          star_rate = 0
          for rating in star_ratings:
              # print(rating.get_attribute('src'))
              if (rating.get_attribute('src') == stars):
                  star_rate = star_rate + 1
          rating_csv.append(star_rate)
          print(star_rate)

          # Date of Review
          date = product.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='title right']").text
          date_review_csv.append(date)
          print(date)

      #Check for button next-pagination-item have disable attribute then jump from loop else click on the next button
      if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button.next-pagination-item.next[disabled]"))>0:
          break;
      else:
          button_next=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.next-pagination-item.next")))
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_next)
          print("next page")
          time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
print(review_csv)
print(product_csv)
print(rating_csv)
print(date_review_csv)
```

---

**List printed like:**

```
['Fast delivery, send within 3 days, in bubble envelope. Product expiry date : 0522', 'received in good condition. have not try it yet', 'No comments/review is an image', 'No comments/review is an image', 'No comments/review is an image', 'No comments/review is an image', 'No comments/review is an image', 'No comments/review is an image']
```

---

```
['Volume (ml):30', 'Volume (ml):30', 'Volume (ml):30', 'Volume (ml):30', 'Volume (ml):30', 'Volume (ml):30', 'Volume (ml):30', 'Volume (ml):30']
```

---

```
[5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

---

```
['24 Oct 2019', '17 Nov 2019', '21 Nov 2019', '25 Oct 2019', '29 Aug 2019', '24 Apr 2019', '19 Jan 2019', '11 Nov 2018']
```

Comment: Hi, but i encounter an error when running the code above.

  File "Review.py", line 61, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_next)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Comment: Check if you have compatible chrome version on your system https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads